# Поиск слова в первом предложении, которого нет в последующих

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Я тут делаю лабораторную роботу, вроде все продумал, но как то завис на месте.
Важно использовать именно StringBuffer и регулярные выражения.
Вот кусок кода:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] tokens = new String[100];
    StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer("This is a test message. This is test word ");
    strTokenizer(str, tokens);
}

public static void strTokenizer(StringBuffer str, String[] tokens) {
    int elements = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    String separator = " ";        
    while(str.charAt(elements) != '.') {
        if(str.charAt(elements + 1) == ' ') {
            end = str.indexOf(separator, start);
            if(end > 0) {
                tokens[i++] = (str.substring(start, end));
                start = end + separator.length();
            }
            else tokens[i++] = (str.substring(start));   
        }   
        elements++;
    }
    end = str.indexOf(".", start);
    tokens[i++] = (str.substring(start, end));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для такого существует negative lookahead, выглядеть будет так:

```
(?P<word>\b\w+\b)(?!.+(?P=word))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Fy1BxK07efMmSSyn)

---

Ищем слово, сохраняем в группу `word`, потом используем negative lookahead в поисках любых символов и последующего слова.